# Get value from properties file in enum class

Tags: java, spring, enums, properties

team!
I have a question for getting properties file in enum class.
So first of all I have a properties file with the following constant:
MY_CONSTANT="xyz"

Also I have an enum class:

```
public enum Test {
ABC{..},
DEH{..};
.....
String constantTwo = <here_is_constant_from_properties_file>;
}
```

As you know I can not use @Autowired Environment in the enum class, so this.environment.getProperty("MY_CONSTANT") is not working for me.

Also when I try using @Value:

```
public enum Test {
ABC{..},
DEH{..};
.....
@Value(${"MY_CONSTANT"})
String constantTwo;
}
```

I get compile error: constantTwo might not be initialised.

Could you please give some ideas?

Comment: Don't use enums this way.

Comment: Enum values are not Spring beans, therefore `@Autowired` and `@Value` do not work. Possible solution: Don't try to do this in the enum itself. Let the enum contain just the constants, and create a separate class (which may be a Spring bean) which manages the property values and which knows how to get the property value for each enum constant.